# multi-threading problem for NEST simulator

Tags: python, nest-simulator

I want to use [multi-threading function](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/nest-2.20.1/guides/parallel_computing.html#using-multiple-threads) in [NEST simulator (version 2.20.1)](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/nest-2.20.1/contents.html). However, it gives a warning `No multithreading available, using single threading`. Can anyone help me to solve it?

I install NEST simulator using conda command

```
conda create --name nest -c conda-forge nest-simulator
```

Below is my code and output:

```
(nest) edward@edward-MacBook-Pro ~ % python             
Python 3.9.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan 10 2021, 02:52:42) 
[Clang 11.0.0 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

\>>> import nest

[INFO] [2021.1.14 11:32:57 /Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/nest-simulator_1607081529208/work/nestkernel/rng_manager.cpp:217 @ Network::create_rngs_] : Creating default RNGs

[INFO] [2021.1.14 11:32:57 /Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/nest-simulator_1607081529208/work/nestkernel/rng_manager.cpp:260 @ Network::create_grng_] : Creating new default global RNG

N E S T

Copyright (C) 2004 The NEST Initiative

 Version: nest-2.20.1
 Built: Dec  4 2020 11:38:17

 This program is provided AS IS and comes with
 NO WARRANTY. See the file LICENSE for details.

 Problems or suggestions?
   Visit https://www.nest-simulator.org

 Type 'nest.help()' to find out more about NEST.

\>>> **nest.SetKernelStatus({"local_num_threads": 4})**

**Jan 14 11:33:02 VPManager::set_status [Warning]: 
    No multithreading available, using single threading**

Jan 14 11:33:02 ModelManager::clear_models_ [Info]: 
    Models will be cleared and parameters reset.

Jan 14 11:33:02 Network::create_rngs_ [Info]: 
    Deleting existing random number generators

Jan 14 11:33:02 Network::create_rngs_ [Info]: 
    Creating default RNGs

Jan 14 11:33:02 Network::create_grng_ [Info]: 
    Creating new default global RNG
```

Comment: Welcome to the community, it will be great if you can copy and paste the code along with the log to your question :)

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the conda package for MacOS. Developers are looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed a bug, that should be fixed in the latest build.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed it on Linux instead. Hope the bug will be fixed soon.

Comment: It should be fixed already. If you still encounter problems on the MacOS build, please let us know.